# WCF API versioning with ixmlserializable

Tags: wcf

I'm working on API versioning in WCF these days. I've read many articles regarding best practices of doing this. What I've to understand the most important thing is to identify either changes in API are Breaking or Non Breaking in new version. A very nice article/discussion on Changes impact on stackoverflow [WCF API Deployment Versioning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8703854/wcf-api-deployment-versioning)

To implement custom Serialization requirement I've chosen ixmlserializable technique. Now my question is Either Breaking and Non Breaking concept will remain same in this case? If no, please help me to find out the way to implement API versioning in this context.

My understanding is that new changes will always break when working ixmlserializable because ReadXml method implement the manual way to construct the object.

Please do let me know either my understanding is correct and how to proceed in this scenario. Any help in this regard will be highly appreciable.

/Rizwan

Comment: Anxiously Waiting for some response ;(